# WrapPanel in VirtualizingStackPanel doesn't repaint properly on resize

Tags: c#, wpf, virtualization, wrappanel

I have a ItemsControl that have virtualization. As DataTemplate I have a WrapPanel. The problem is when I resize the container the wrap panel doesn't repaint properly. It crates new rows to wrap the text but the text remains on the top row.

I have created a simple test project to show the problem.
Here is the XAML: (MainWindow.xaml)

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Height="350"
        Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="ItemsControlStyle"
               TargetType="ItemsControl">
            <Setter Property="Background"
                    Value="White" />
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll"
                    Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing"
                    Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <VirtualizingStackPanel IsItemsHost="True" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ItemsControl">
                        <ScrollViewer BorderThickness="0"
                                      CanContentScroll="True"
                                      Padding="{TemplateBinding Control.Padding}"
                                      Background="{TemplateBinding Panel.Background}"
                                      HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"
                                      VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility}"
                                      Focusable="False">
                            <ItemsPresenter />
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <ItemsControl Name="Items"
                  Grid.Row="1"
                  AlternationCount="2"
                  Style="{StaticResource ItemsControlStyle}"
                  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <WrapPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="Wrap Item" />
                    <TextBlock Text="Wrap Item" />
                    <TextBlock Text="Wrap Item" />
                    <TextBlock Text="Wrap Item" />
                    <TextBlock Text="Wrap Item" />
                    <TextBlock Text="Wrap Item" />
                    <TextBlock Text="Wrap Item" />
                    <TextBlock Text="Wrap Item" />
                    <TextBlock Text="Wrap Item" />
                    <TextBlock Text="Wrap Item" />
                    <TextBlock Text="Wrap Item" />
                    <TextBlock Text="Wrap Item" />
                    <TextBlock Text="Wrap Item" />
                    <TextBlock Text="Wrap Item" />
                    <TextBlock Text="Wrap Item" />
                    <TextBlock Text="Wrap Item" />
                    <TextBlock Text="Wrap Item" />
                    <TextBlock Text="Wrap Item" />
                    <TextBlock Text="Wrap Item" />
                    <TextBlock Text="Wrap Item" />
                    <TextBlock Text="Wrap Item" />
                    <TextBlock Text="Wrap Item" />
                    <TextBlock Text="Wrap Item" />
                    <TextBlock Text="Wrap Item" />
                    <TextBlock Text="Wrap Item" />
                    <TextBlock Text="Wrap Item" />
                    <TextBlock Text="Wrap Item" />
                    <TextBlock Text="Wrap Item" />
                    <TextBlock Text="Wrap Item" />
                </WrapPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Window>
```

And here is the Code: (MainWindow.xaml.cs)

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.Items.ItemsSource = Enumerable.Range( 0, 30 );
        }
    }
}
```